# Can not create a new Laravel project on Fedora 36 with composer because the PHP rename function throws permission denied

Tags: laravel, composer-php, fedora

I tried to create a new Laravel project on Fedora 36 with composer by issuing: `composer create-project laravel/laravel chirper`. After installing all packages the following error occurs:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   INFO  Discovering packages.  


   ErrorException 

  rename(/home/timo/lele/chirper/bootstrap/cache/packages.phpHR6TgD,/home/timo/lele/chirper/bootstrap/cache/packages.php): Permission denied

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:214
    210▕         chmod($tempPath, 0777 - umask());
    211▕ 
    212▕         file_put_contents($tempPath, $content);
    213▕ 
  ➜ 214▕         rename($tempPath, $path);
    215▕     }
    216▕ 
    217▕     /**
    218▕      * Replace a given string within a given file.

      +17 vendor frames 
  18  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I am running PHP Version 8.1.14 and Composer Version 2.5.1. It looks like there is an permission problem. But this looks odd to me because I run the command with user timo and the permissions in /home/timo/lele/chirper/bootstrap/cache/ are:

```
chirper ls -la bootstrap/cache
total 32
drwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo   104 Jan 29 12:14 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo    24 Jan 11 16:50 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 timo timo    14 Jan 11 16:50 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo  1082 Jan 29 12:14 packages.php
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo  1082 Jan 29 12:14 packages.phpHR6TgD
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo 19191 Jan 29 12:14 services.php
```

I tried to give maximum permissions to all files in the created directory with `chmod -R a+rwx ./`. Still, the error occurs when I run `composer install`. Then the permissions look as follows:

```
chirper ls -la bootstrap/cache
total 44
drwxrwxrwx. 1 timo timo   212 Jan 29 12:31 .
drwxrwxrwx. 1 timo timo    24 Jan 11 16:50 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 timo timo    14 Jan 11 16:50 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo  1082 Jan 29 12:31 packages.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 timo timo  1082 Jan 29 12:29 packages.phpEdJiAo
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 timo timo  1082 Jan 29 12:14 packages.phpHR6TgD
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo  1082 Jan 29 12:31 packages.phpmGjrq8
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 timo timo  1082 Jan 29 12:30 packages.phpT6607S
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 timo timo 19191 Jan 29 12:31 services.php
```

Comment: Did you try with `sudo` just to see what permissions it ends up with? Also, have in mind that maybe it does not have permissions on the parent folders, not exactly on `cache` or an specific file

Comment: Another possibility is a selinux file context, etc.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I just ran `sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel chirper` and it worked. The permissions afterwards were the same as in the question except everything is now owned by root. Permissions of the parent directories look all fine to me, everything 755 and owned by timo.

Comment: if you use `755` that will never work, it needs to be `777`

Comment: @rickhg12hs I don't know much about that stuff, what could be wrong there?

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for helping. I gave recursively 777 to the parent and it still doesen't work. I think the problem is that laravel creates new files like `packages.phpmGjrq8` during the installation and than the rename function fails bacause after creation they have 755 permissions.

Comment: If they are creating it as X user, executing the rename will use the same user... so if you have `777`, it will work... I am assuming you have a parent folder that does not have something right...

Comment: @rickhg12hs I disabeld SELinux and still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue, I tried everything around permissions but in the end I fixed it by regenerating the `composer.lock` (fully deleting and running `composer update`

The only other changes that I think might be related was to also ensure hte conents of `storage/framework/cache/.gitignore` was

```
*
!data/
!.gitignore
```

And that an empty `storage/framework/cache/data` directory exists with a `.gitignore` inside.